# Best element for clearing floats in CSS?

Tags: css, css-float

I was wondering what the best element for clearing floated block-level elements would be?

For now, I mostly used a div or a p element with clear: both; applied.

What elements do you prefer, or what is something like the "best practice" for doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by "best element"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really just want to clear them, then whatever element best describes the semantics of the content that you want to clear the float.

If you want to cause a block to expand to contain all it's floating content, then adding an extra element (of any type) is the dirtiest option. There are [a whole bunch of better ways to achieve the effect](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/59). I generally favour setting `overflow: hidden` on the container, but the best option varies a little with the context.

If you really want to use an actual (empty) element, then either a div or as span is best — they don't come with extra semantics.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following context:

```
<div id="sidebarWrap">
    <div id="sidebarHandle">
        <a href="#"></a>
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <h2>Category</h2>                           
    </div>
    <p class="clear"></p>
</div>
```

Where #sidebarWrap is absolutely positioned to the top right of it's parent, and #sidebarHandle and #sidebar are floated to be next to each other. 
the p.clear clears the floating.

In this case, would there be a better solution?

Comment: This should've gone as an edit on your question...To answer your question: It depends on the content. If the content has a static size, then you could do as David suggests: `overflow:hidden` on the sidebarWrap. If the content changes in size, you've probably got the best solution right there...

Comment: Alright. I have varying content here. 
For other cases I will try out the overflow technique :-)

Comment: The size of the content isn't going to make any difference as to overflow Vs extra element being better.